# #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now; Using in functions

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I had a problem doing this query:

```
SELECT func_total_facturas_cliente(cli_codigo,2,"no") AS totalCreditos
FROM cliente
```

The function is this:

```
BEGIN
    declare totalAbonos double; 

    declare total cursor for
        SELECT SUM(faca_abono) FROM abono_facturacredito_ventas 
         WHERE cli_codigo = cliCodigo COLLATE latin1_general_ci;

     OPEN total;
        FETCH total INTO totalAbonos;
    CLOSE total;

    RETURN totalAbonos;
END
```

The specific problem is that it skips that error only when it is running in the phpmyadmin of the server, how could I improve the query or function to correct that error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions in English please on this site.

Comment: ok, thanks. You can already read it in english, now

Comment: @mrangel17 you and I are from the same town :). Regarding your question: you don't need a cursor for that. You can simply do `select @totalAbonos = SUM(faca_abono) from abono_facturacredito_ventas 
         WHERE cli_codigo = cliCodigo`. And that's enough.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tired to do this. BEGIN
 declare totalAbonos double;
 
  'SELECT @totalAbonos = SUM(faca_abono) FROM abono_facturacredito_ventas 
         WHERE cli_codigo = cliCodigo COLLATE latin1_general_ci;

     OPEN total;
  FETCH total INTO totalAbonos;
 CLOSE total;

    RETURN totalAbonos;
END'
But I did not get good results, What else can I do? Thanks

Comment: @mrangel17 See my answer and Fiddle. That should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a SQL-Fiddle that will help you:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jrwvJHt2PYLsXbhqWVW9FC/1

I will copy it here as well:

```
create table abono_facturacredito_ventas 
(
  faca_abono double,
  cli_codigo nvarchar(50)
);

create table clientes 
(
cli_codigo nvarchar(30),
 nombre nvarchar(20)
);
```

Now insert some test data:

```
insert into abono_facturacredito_ventas (faca_abono, cli_codigo) values (31,'abc');
insert into abono_facturacredito_ventas(faca_abono, cli_codigo) values (3,'abc');
insert into abono_facturacredito_ventas(faca_abono, cli_codigo) values (32,'abc');
insert into abono_facturacredito_ventas(faca_abono, cli_codigo) values (34,'xyxz');


insert into clientes (cli_codigo, nombre) values ('abc','Ricardo');
insert into clientes (cli_codigo, nombre) values ('xyxz','Caro');
```

Now declare the function (note: my syntax was wrong on the comment I left you):

```
CREATE FUNCTION func_total_facturas_cliente(codigo nvarchar(50)) RETURNS double
    DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN

    select SUM(faca_abono) into @totalAbonos from abono_facturacredito_ventas WHERE cli_codigo = codigo;

    return @totalAbonos;
END
```

Now use it as so:

```
select func_total_facturas_cliente(cli_codigo) as total_abonos, nombre from clientes ;
```

Comment: Your response has been very helpful, I was able to solve my problem, thank you very much